Discard indirect buffer showing details of the selected task on leaving agenda
Using Doom Emacs.
When I open org agenda and take cursor to a task, it opens an indirect buffer showing the task at the bottom of the window. This is super-useful.
I never use this buffer to edit. I just use it to see additional information like if it is a recurring task.
How do I automatically discard this indirect buffer on quitting org-agenda?

Do you know the name of the buffer? Or have access to through a variable? If so, you can (kill-buffer <buffer-or-name>). You can then advise org-agend-quit to do the killing. IOW, it's more a matter of knowing which buffer to kill. The rest is straightforward.

@NickD Thanks. The name of the buffer keeps changing as I select different tasks. But I am OK with killing all frames in the current window. Typically, I only see the agenda in one frame and the indirect buffer in the other. Any hope?

Are you sure it's an indirect buffer? How do you know? Generally speaking (i.e. in non-Doom scenarios), the agenda opens all the agenda files and keeps them open: you don't want to kill these buffers (but you can bury them). Then when you go to an agenda item and press RET, the corresponding buffer is popped up in another window - but it is NOT an indirect buffer. You can check whether a buffer is indirect, by evaluating M-: (buffer-base-buffer) in it: if it is an indirect buffer, the call will return the base buffer, but if it is not, it will return nil.

If Doom does indeed create an indirect buffer, then you'll have to figure out how exactly it does that, so that you can save the buffers in a list, so that org-agenda-quit can kill them.
